# Trouble with creating join when making monad instance of an object

Tags: haskell, monads

I currently have a newtype instance which I should translate into a monad. I am having trouble with defining the bind to this particular monad where the newtype is defined as:

```
newtype Thing xs = Thing {runThing :: [[xs]]} deriving (Show)
```

I have defined a join that takes the monad one level down.

```
join' :: Thing(Thing a) -> Thing a
join' xs = (concat (map runThing (concat (Thing xs))))
```

and planned to apply the function in the bind like so

```
Thing xs >>= f = Thing(map (map f) $ (runThing (Thing xs)))
```

which doesn't compile and also tried:

```
join' xs =  head (concat (runThing xs))
Thing a >>= f =join' (fmap f (Thing a))
```

does but I understand that it only maps to the head of a list and uses the fmap I defined in a functor like so:

```
instance Functor  Thing where
    fmap f (Thing [[]]) = Thing [[]]
    fmap f (Thing a) = Thing (nestedMap f a)
```

How would I build a join that allows me to map and create a new Thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest fix to your original definition of `join'` is to use `runThing` instead of `Thing`, and then add a top-level wrapper:

```
join' xs = Thing (concat (map runThing (concat (runThing xs))))
```

We can then define `(>>=)` in terms of `fmap` and `join'` in the standard way:

```
xss >>= f = join' (fmap f xss)
```

Unfortunately, this definition doesn't satisfy the monad laws:

```
> Thing [[1,2]] >>= return
Thing [[1],[2]]
```

The laws require that the result of that computation be again `Thing [[1,2]]`.

<s>However, using the *swap* construction from [Composing Monads](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/pubs/RR-1004.pdf) with `swap = sequence`, we can construct this alternate `join'`:</s>

```
join' = Thing . join . fmap (fmap join . sequence . fmap runThing) . runThing
```

I believe, though I have not proven, that the conditions required of `swap` are satisfied, so that this whole construction may be used to produce a law-abiding monad.

The construction proposed above fails the associativity law. Rats! In conclusion: everything I've tried so far to give an alternate `join'` fails at least one of the monad laws.

Comment: Happened to see that too when i added that same exact line with bind

Comment: @Killimanjaro Never mind, I was wrong as usual. Even the *swap* construction doesn't work properly; I should have known I would have to sit down and prove the conditions they stated instead of just guessing. The construction seems to satisfy the identity laws, but the associativity law is still not satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

A `Thing` contains a list of list of `a`s. So that means that a `Thing (Thing a)` contains a list of list of `Thing a`s, and these thus contain a list of list of `a`s.

We could thus concatenate these lists together. We can first unpack the outer `Thing`, which will give us a `[[ Thing a ]]`. By using [**`concat :: Foldable f => f [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat), we convert this to a `[Thing a]`. Now we can use [**`concatMap :: Foldable f => (a -> [b]) -> f a -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) with `runThing` as function, to transform this to a `[[a]]`, and then we can wrap that value back in a `Thing`:

```
join' :: Thing (Thing a) -> Thing a
join' (Thing xs) = Thing (concatMap runThing (concat xs))
```

Comment: Isnt that essentially what have in join' originally? Also thank you.

Comment: @Killimanjaro: In your `join'` you wrapped the value in a `Thing`, instead of unwrapping. Notice the `concat xs`, and the the `Things xs` in the head. Not vice versa.

Comment: ...but even after this fix, the monad laws are not satisfied. See my answer.

Comment: @DanielWagner: no indeed, I'm not sure we can construct a monad here.